# My device can't show image array, but has no trouble finding the seperate images

Tags: ios, arrays, image, device

In one of the views of my app, i want to display different animations made from a number of `jpg` images with the following code...

```
    for (i = 0; i <= HighPic; i = i+1) {

        [self.imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%i", imageName, i] ofType:@"jpg"]]];
    }

    float imageCount = [[[self.selfContent objectAtIndex:overPath] valueForKey:@"lastImageNumber"] floatValue]*2-1;

    imageView.animationImages = self.imageArray;

    [imageView setAnimationRepeatCount:0];
    imageView.animationDuration = (imageCount/25);
    [imageView startAnimating];
```

This works fine inside the simulator, but when i run it on my device, the `self.imageArray` is equal `null`. If i instead write:

```
    [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@0", imageName] ofType:@"jpg"]]];
```

It shows the right picture, even on the device, but just not the animations...

The reason i'm not using the

```
    [self.imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%i", imageName, i]]];
```

Is because it takes up too much memory...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is allocated/defined `self.imageArray`?

Comment: It's in my .h file 
@property(nonatomic, weak) NSMutableArray *exerciseImageArray;

Comment: He means that you have to init the array before adding objects to it `self.imageArray= [NSMutableArray new];`

Comment: Oh, right! Yeah i did `self.imageArray = [NSMutableArray array];` right before the animation code

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the code myself. When i went to the `.h` file i saw the `imageArray` was set to `weak` so i replaced it with `strong` and that fixed it :)